# Arabic words representation after using split() function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, arabic

I have a problem with representing Arabic words after using split() function in Python. I used Arabic text as input file (you can try any Arabic source).

here is my original code I worked on it derived from [here](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/generating-pseudo-random-text-using-markov-chains/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf8


from pprint import pprint
from random import choice
import codecs



# ----------------------build deictionary--------------------------
EOS = ['.', '?', '!']
file=u'C:\python27\نجود.txt'
fname = open(file, 'r')
#file1=codecs.open(file , 'r', 'utf-8')
text = fname.read()
#text=file1.read()
words = text.split()
d = {}
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    try:
        first, second, third = words[i], words[i + 1], words[i + 2]
    except IndexError:
        break
    key = (first, second)
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = []
        #
    d[key].append(third)

pprint (d)
    #for k, v in d.iteritems():
      #  print k, v
# -------------------------generate text---------------------------
li = []
first, second = key
li.append(first)
li.append(second)
while True:
    try:

        third = choice(d[key])  
    except KeyError:
        break
    li.append(third)
    if third[-1] in EOS:  
        break
    # else
    key = (second, third)
    first, second = key

gtext = ' '.join(li)
#decoded = gtext.decode('utf8')
print "النص المنشأ:", gtext
#file1.close()
```

the output I need that same as if I use English input file it will be like this:

```
{('He', 'is'): ['happy.',
                'happy.',
                'going.',
                'sleep.',
                'sad.',
                'happy.',
                'happy.',
                'sleep.',
                'angry.',
                'angry.'],
 ('angry.', 'He'): ['is', 'is'],
 ('going.', 'He'): ['is'],
 ('happy.', 'He'): ['is', 'is', 'is', 'is'],
 ('is', 'angry.'): ['He', 'He'],
 ('is', 'going.'): ['He'],
 ('is', 'happy.'): ['He', 'He', 'He', 'He'],
 ('is', 'sad.'): ['He'],
 ('is', 'sleep.'): ['He', 'He'],
 ('sad.', 'He'): ['is'],
 ('sleep.', 'He'): ['is', 'is'],
 ('He', 'is'): ['angry.']}
```

But the words appears like unreadable text:

```
    {('\xd8\xa3\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7', '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb5\xd8\xaf\xd8\xaf'):['\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9'],('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xac','\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a'): ['\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86.'('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a', '\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd9\x83\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'): ['\xd9\x85\xd8\xae\xd8\xaa\xd9\x84\xd9\x81\xd8\xa9.'],('\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86','\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xb9'): ['\xd9\x88\xd8\xac\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84,','\xd9\x88\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd9\x82'],('\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86','\xd9\x85\xd8\xb9'): ['\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a'('\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86.', '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'): ['\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xb9'],('\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb5\xd8\xaf\xd8\xaf', '\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9'): ['\xd9\x87\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa7'],('\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9', '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'): ['\xd9\x85\xd8\xb9'],('\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9', '\xd9\x87\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa7'): ['\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xac'],('\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xb9', '\xd9\x88\xd8\xac\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84,'): ['\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x83\xd9\x86'],('\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xb9', '\xd9\x88\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd9\x82'): ['\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9.'],('\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd9\x83\xd9\x88\xd9\x86', '\xd9\x85\xd8\xae\xd8\xaa\xd9\x84\xd9\x81\xd8\xa9.'): ['\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'],('\xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x83\xd9\x85', '\xd8\xa3\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7'): ['\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb5\xd8\xaf\xd8\xaf'],('\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a', '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86.'): ['\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'],('\xd9\x85\xd8\xae\xd8\xaa\xd9\x84\xd9\x81\xd8\xa9.', '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'): ['\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xb9'],('\xd9\x85\xd8\xb9', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a'): ['\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd9\x83\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'],('\xd9\x87\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa7', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xac'): ['\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a'],('\xd9\x88\xd8\xac\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84,', '\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x83\xd9\x86'): ['\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9'],('\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x83\xd9\x86', '\xd8\xaa\xd8\xac\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa9'): ['\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xab\xd9\x88\xd9\x86'],('\xef\xbb\xbf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85', '\xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x83\xd9\x85'): ['\xd8\xa3\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7']}
```

Or like this if Python 3:

```
{('ï»؟ط§ظ„ط³ظ„ط§ظ…', 'ط¹ظ„ظٹظƒظ…'): ['ط£ظ†ط§'],
 ('ط£ظ†ط§', 'ط¨طµط¯ط¯'): ['طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©'],
 ('ط§ظ„ط¨ط±ظ†ط§ظ…ط¬', 'ظپظٹ'): ['ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†.'],
 ('ط§ظ„ط¹ط±ط¨ظٹ', 'ط³طھظƒظˆظ†'): ['ظ…ط®طھظ„ظپط©.'],
 ('ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†', 'ط±ط§ط¦ط¹'): ['ظˆط¬ظ…ظٹظ„,', 'ظˆظٹط³طھط\xadظ‚'],
 ('ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†', 'ظ…ط¹'): ['ط§ظ„ط¹ط±ط¨ظٹ'],
 ('ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†.', 'ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'): ['ط±ط§ط¦ط¹'],
 ('ط¨طµط¯ط¯', 'طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©'): ['ظ‡ط°ط§'],
 ('ط±ط§ط¦ط¹', 'ظˆط¬ظ…ظٹظ„,'): ['ظˆظ„ظƒظ†'],
 ('ط±ط§ط¦ط¹', 'ظˆظٹط³طھط\xadظ‚'): ['ط§ظ„طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©.'],
 ('ط³طھظƒظˆظ†', 'ظ…ط®طھظ„ظپط©.'): ['ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'],
 ('ط¹ظ„ظٹظƒظ…', 'ط£ظ†ط§'): ['ط¨طµط¯ط¯'],
 ('طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©', 'ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'): ['ظ…ط¹'],
 ('طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©', 'ظ‡ط°ط§'): ['ط§ظ„ط¨ط±ظ†ط§ظ…ط¬'],
 ('ظˆط¬ظ…ظٹظ„,', 'ظˆظ„ظƒظ†'): ['طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©'],
 ('ظˆظ„ظƒظ†', 'طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©'): ['ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'],
 ('ظپظٹ', 'ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†.'): ['ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'],
 ('ظ‡ط°ط§', 'ط§ظ„ط¨ط±ظ†ط§ظ…ط¬'): ['ظپظٹ'],
 ('ظ…ط®طھظ„ظپط©.', 'ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†'): ['ط±ط§ط¦ط¹'],
 ('ظ…ط¹', 'ط§ظ„ط¹ط±ط¨ظٹ'): ['ط³طھظƒظˆظ†']}
```

I've been tried many solutions and still the problem have not yet solved

I tried:

Solution 1:

```
stack= d.items()
    while stack:
        k, v = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            stack.extend(v.iteritems())
        else:
            output= "%s: %s" % (k, v)
            print output.decode('utf8')
```

Solution 2:

```
 for k, v in d.items():
       print k, v
```

Solution 3:

```
for k, v in d.keys():
    print k, v
    for attribute, value in d.items():
        print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```

Solution 4:

```
 words = text.split()
    uniwords= unicode(words)
    print uniwords
```

but the problem still exist. Also I tried `codecs` module but still prints like above output. This problem is actually appeared with only if I use file I/O not with a normal text.

So what I need is, if I print split function it should be printed in Arabic words as in English example.

Comment: Is the problem that the `repr` of the strings is shown as a sequence of bytes?

Comment: the output I need that if I use split() function I want to see the words as Arabic words in the output not something like above output.

Comment: `print '\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb5\xd8\xaf\xd8\xaf'.decode('utf-8')` displays `بصدد`.

Comment: this not what i need, i actually need the output of split function like if I use English file it prints without any problem. maybe i need to edit my Q so u can understand me more

Comment: If you want your container datatypes to display unicode strings in a readable format, you must switch to python 3.

Comment: Can you restructure your question with: 1. input data (where does it come from??), 2. your code and solutions, 3. output data, 4. how you want output data to look.?

Comment: I updated the Q with Python 3 output

Comment: the problem is solved by move to python 3 and rewrite the code not copy and paste. thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3, you need to change `fname = open(file, 'r')` to `fname = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`.

---

**Example:** run the following code on your file:

```
with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    l = f.read()
    print(l.split())
```

You will get a list of words split by `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to open the file with your default OS encoding, while the file is probably encoded in UTF-8. You need to:

```
open('...', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Also, unless you have a smashing good reason, try to stay away from Python 2.7. It's both old and very hard to get right with unicode strings.